# Android - How do I save a photo in the gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I need to save a photo in the gallery. 
The code below helps if I have my photo on a sd-card. But what should I do if I have no sdcard? Only bytes or temporary file?

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), src, title , description);
```

Comment: are capturing the image from camera or getting image from webservice..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title", null);
```

Comment: Sorry, vote Up requires 15 reputation, when I'll have it, I'll vote